# How can I get intellisense to start working again in my razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So I installed a trial version of Windows 8 and started having issues my Visual Web Developer 2010 Express so I uninstalled Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  After re-installing the Web Developer I noticed that the code in the views no longer allows intellisense to happen.  Is there some additional component that I need to download?

Comment: Did you unplug it and plug it back in?  :)  Try restarting Visual Web Developer and/or closing and reopening the files.

Comment: do you have any productivity pluggins running like resharper or coderush ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have another Visual Studio product installed, like, say, another Express SKU?  The behavior you're seeing is something that does occasionally happen if you've installed multiple pre-release versions of Visual Studio products and they don't all have the same build number.

Because these products share some components, some of the assemblies you're using will have the wrong version, and the lack of code coloring or intellisense in some scenarios is the first sign of trouble that you'll see.

If this is the case, the fix is simple; just update all of the Visual Studio products you have to the shipped version.

HTH,
Clay

Comment: Thanks... I updated as much packages as I thought I needed and intellisense is back